# How to get the date of when the user was added to group?

Tags: powershell

I have automating our change procedure and checking groups for users. If they are already added to the group, the script will detect this and not add the user to group. However, we want to log when that user was added to the group before the change procedure so we can figure out why this happened.

Is there a way I can query the list of members for a group for the date the member was added?

Answer (score 0):

Event logs might save you.
*4728/4729 > A member was added/removed to/from a security-enabled global group
4732/4733 > A member was added/removed to/from a security-enabled local group
4756/4757 > A member was added/removed to/from a security-enabled universal group
4751/4752 > A member was added/removed to/from a security-disabled global group (distribution list)
4746/4747 > A member was added/removed to/from a security-disabled local group (distribution list)
4761/4762 > A member was added/removed to/from a security-disabled universal group (distribution list)*

```
Get-EventLog -logname security | Where-Object {($_.eventid -eq 4732) -or ($_.eventid -eq 4733 ) -or ($_.eventid -eq 4746)} | select EventID,MachineName,EntryType,Message,InstanceId,TimeGenerated,Timecreated,UserName | fl | export-csv -path C:\logs.csv
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, after attempting this, it looks like it requires additional security permission. The account being used does not have the required permission.

Answer (score -1):

This script is awesome

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Find-the-time-a-user-was-a0bfc0cf

just run the script and look for the group details

```
Get-ADGroupMemberDate -Group 'Domain Admins'
```

Comment: I actually just saw this script after I posted this, however, repadmin.exe isn't available. I was hoping that AD tracked this data.